# Slickgrid Combobox how to implement value-display type binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox, slickgrid

Using examples from web, I've tried to implement my own customized combobox (YesNoEditor) where it allows both display and value members to be saved. The idea is to have the HTML output of SELECT tag to contain both an option value and an actual text to be displayed like so:

```
("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-yesno'><OPTION value='valuemember'>DisplayMember</OPTION></SELECT>");
```

And here's my modified version of YesNoEditor from slick.editors.js

```
    function YesNoSelectEditor(args) {
      var $select;
      var defaultValue;
      var scope = this;

      this.init = function () {

          if (args.column.options && args.column.display) {
              opt_display = args.column.display.split(',');
              opt_values = args.column.options.split(',');
          } else {
              opt_values = "yes,no".split(',');
          }
          option_str = "";
          for (i in opt_values) {
              v = opt_values[i];
              d = opt_display[i];
              option_str += "<OPTION value='" + v + "'>" + d + "</OPTION>";
          }
          $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select'>" + option_str + "</SELECT>");
          $select.appendTo(args.container);
          $select.focus();
      };

      this.getDefaultValue = function () {
          return defaultValue;
      };


      this.destroy = function () {
          $select.remove();
      };

      this.focus = function () {
          $select.focus();
      };

      this.loadValue = function (item) {
          defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
          $select.val(defaultValue);
      };

      this.getSelectValue = function () {
          if (args.column.options) {
              return $select.val();
          }
      }

      this.serializeValue = function () {
          if (args.column.options) {
              return $select.children("option:selected").text();
          } else {
              return ($select.val() == "yes");
          }
      };

      this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
          item[args.column.field] = state;
      };

      this.isValueChanged = function () {
          return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
      };

      this.validate = function () {
          return {
              valid: true,
              msg: null
          };
      };

      this.init();
  }
```

This mostly works, except when I try to manually click the combobox, it sporadically changes the text value to something other than its previously selected value. For instance, the combobox could've had display value 2 but as soon as I click on the cell to activate the combobox, the display value changes to 1.

Is there any good alternative method to accomplish what I need?

-----Edit2

Here's an example of how I define the column using YesNoEditor

```
{ id: "Type", name: "Customer Type", width: 100, field: "Type", editor: Slick.Editors.YesNoSelect, options: customerTypeList.join(","), display: customerTypeList.join(",")},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the `this.loadValue` function... This is the piece of code I use and it always make the dropdown to open with the correct selection:

```
this.loadValue = function(item) {
    defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
    $select.val(defaultValue);
};
```

It's worth a try, hopefully that would be it...let me know

**EDIT**
Here is my complete code for custom , I can pass custom values or use the default yes/no when it doesn't find anything:

```
function SelectEditor(args) {
    var $select;
    var defaultValue;
    var scope = this;

    this.init = function() {

        if(args.column.editorOptions.options){
            tabOptions = args.column.editorOptions.options.split(',');
            if(args.column.editorOptions.values)
                tabValues = args.column.editorOptions.values.split(',');
        }else{
            tabOptions ="yes,no".split(',');
        }
        var option_str = "";
        for( i in tabOptions ){
            var opt = $.trim( tabOptions[i] ); // remove any white space including spaces after comma
            //var val = (typeof tabValues == 'undefined') ? tabOptions[i] : tabValues[i];
            option_str += "<OPTION value='"+opt+"'>"+opt+"</OPTION>";
        }
        $select = $("<SELECT tabIndex='0' class='editor-select'>"+ option_str +"</SELECT>");
        $select.appendTo(args.container);
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        $select.remove();
    };

    this.focus = function() {
        $select.focus();
    };

    this.loadValue = function(item) {
        defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
        $select.val(defaultValue);
    };

    this.serializeValue = function() {
        if(args.column.editorOptions.options){
            return $select.val();
        }else{
            return ($select.val() == "yes");
        }
    };

    this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
        item[args.column.field] = state;
    };

    this.isValueChanged = function() {
        return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
    };

    this.validate = function() {
        return {
            valid: true,
            msg: null
        };
    };

    this.init();
}
```

I realized that I forgot to mention how I call it inside the `columns` array definition...

```
{ id:'column1', field:'column1', name: "Column 1", width:75, editor: Slick.Editors.Select, editorOptions:{options:"val1,val2,val3"}  }
```

**EDIT #2**
Alright after understanding your real need, I changed my code and even tested it to make sure that it works..and it does indeed works like you wanted:

```
    function YesNoSelectEditor(args) {
      var $select;
      ...

      // define both your arrays here so they are global and availble from everywhere
      var opt_values = [];  
      var opt_display = [];

      ... 

    this.loadValue = function (item) {
        var displayedText = item[args.column.field];

        // first find the index position inside your Display Array, ex.: Colorado
        var idxPos = $.inArray(displayedText,opt_display); 

        // second use that index found to get the value, ex.: CO
        defaultValue = opt_values[idxPos];

        // then select that value ex.: $select.val("CO");
        $select.val(defaultValue);
    };

    ...
}
```

Comment: Weird, still getting same issue

Comment: It's not clear in your question if you keep the value of being "yes" or "no" or something completely different...in your first line it's completely different but in your formatter implementation it's not. So can you define a little more your question

Comment: Sorry, I must've been half asleep when I posted the question, it seems like I've posted an old version of the source code. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my code? I realized that I missed a piece, take a look and see if that help. Let me know

Comment: Oh.. perhaps I've phrased my question pretty badly.. I was already able to get a similar working to your example. What I want to have is a display-value type binding for the combobox. For example, the combobox might be displaying "Colorado", but it's internal value might be "CO". I'll edit the question again, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Ahh cheez I just got to understand what you really want..haha sorry again... So in your case then what you need is the position of your value inside your array, let say "CO" is the 3rd in the array then inside the `this.loadValue()` you would have the `$select.val(3);`, let me try to edit again my answer, I don't know how long it will take me

Comment: That's it...I got it working :)   Don't forget to redeclare your arrays as global inside the function so you can access them inside the `this.loadValue()`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to check it yet. I'll try it and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

The solution is with an additional formatter:

`function ComboFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
      var opt_display = ["Text1", "Text2"];
      var opt_values = ["27", "51"];
      var idxPos = $.inArray(value,opt_values);
      return opt_display[idxPos];
}`

`function ComboEditor(args) {
            var $select;
            var defaultValue;
            var scope = this;

```
        this.init = function() {
            $select = $("<select ....<option></....</select>");
            $select.appendTo(args.container);
            $select.focus();
        };

        this.destroy = function() {
            $select.remove();
        };

        this.focus = function() {
            $select.focus();
        };

        this.loadValue = function(item) {
            defaultValue = item[args.column.field] || "";
            $select.val(item[args.column.field]);
            $select.select();
        };

        this.serializeValue = function() {
            return ($select.val());
        };

        this.applyValue = function(item,state) {
            item[args.column.field] = state;
        };

        this.isValueChanged = function() {
            return ($select.val() != defaultValue);
        };

        this.validate = function() {
            return {
                valid: true,
                msg: null
            };
        };

        this.init();
    };                  `
```